# Azure SQL: Create login user only if not exists

Tags: sql-server, azure, authentication, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to create an automated script for creating Azure SQL database over an already existing instance.

I know I can use the automation based in CLI, but I need a little more control about what is created and when.

Now I'm stopped in the login creation. I want to create the login user only if not exists (and alter the password if exists).

This is my code:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.sysusers WHERE name='$(dbUserName)')
    BEGIN
        CREATE LOGIN $(dbUserName) WITH PASSWORD='$(dbUserPassword)';
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        ALTER LOGIN $(dbUserName) WITH PASSWORD='$(dbUserPassword)';
    END
```

My problem comes that sys.sysusers views check database users, not login user. I'm trying to find which system catalog view contain login users, but I'm not able to find (I have also tried database_principals)

NOTE: I have found several alternative for SQL Server on-premise, but they don't work in Azure SQL

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Logins must be created/altered in the context Azure SQL Database logical server master database. Use the `sys.sql_logins` catalog view for this task. The `sys.sysusers` view is provided only for backwards compatibility and should not be used going forward in either Azure or on-prem SQL Server.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.sql_logins WHERE name='$(dbUserName)')
    BEGIN
        CREATE LOGIN $(dbUserName) WITH PASSWORD='$(dbUserPassword)';
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        ALTER LOGIN $(dbUserName) WITH PASSWORD='$(dbUserPassword)';
    END;
```

Comment: I also tried this, but my master database has no sys.sql_logins object. Is it possible something special with the instance? (I didn't not created the instance, it was given to me by subscription admin)

Comment: @Sourcerer, I tested this and it works for me. @@VERSION returns "Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8 Jul 24 2018 14:38:12 Copyright (C) 2018 Microsoft Corporation". Are you sure you are connected to the `master` database?

Comment: My fault!!! :-/ I retested and worked like a charm (I don't know why failed first time)